# Simple usage of Node request not working

Tags: node.js, request

I use request lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for a Node application.

And this simple example doesn't work :

```
console.log(' BEGIN ---- ');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
console.log('END ---- ');
```

I only have **BEGIN ----** and **END ----** messages in my console, but nothing from the get request.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs behaves **asynchronously**, which means when you run your script request takes some time to go and fetch data from the provided link but it will take some time to complete this task therefore other code will not wait for it to complete.

You can use callbacks to wait for the result. Below code is an easy solution for your problem.

```js
const request = require('request')


function req(callback){
    console.log(' BEGIN ---- ');
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      callback()
    }); 
}

req(function(){
    console.log('END ---- ');
})
```

But for more clean and easy to read code you must learn to use promises or async/await feature in nodejs.